# Compojure and Friend where is the state in this example

Tags: clojure, ring

I have written a clojure webapp which looks very much like
the example webapp given [as the friend exmaple](https://github.com/cemerick/friend). I have
written a little test using `ring-mock` to test if the authentication
works properly. Writing this test I found some behaviour I do not understand.

See the following code as an example.

```
(let [route "/login"
      login-post (body (request :post route)
                       {"username" "Username" "password" "Password"})]
  (println (secured-app login-post))
  (println (secured-app login-post)))
```

The first `println` returns the correct result:

```
{:status 303,
 :headers
 {"Set-Cookie"
  ("ring-session=ENCRYPTED-STUFF;Path=/"),
  "Location" "/"},
 :body ""}
```

But the second one returns a login error:

```
{:status 302,
 :headers
 {"Location" "http://localhost/login?&login_failed=Y&username="},
 :body ""}
```

Somewhere in this code there is state being "transmitted" from the first
request being handled to the second request `(secured-app login-post)` but I don't see it.

When I for example run this statement:

```
 (println (secured-app(body (request :post "/login")
                            {"username" "Username" "password" "Password"})))
```

in the repl multiple times, I always get the first proper result.

Where does this behaviour come from and where is the state handeled in this example?

Comment: I made a small lib to store / recreate requests, complete with the body of the request being a stream as ring expects: https://github.com/noisesmith/groundhog It can be added as a ring handler that captures requests as they come in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ring.mock.request/body` function turns the given body data into a mutable ByteArrayInputStream. This means that normally, once your request has been passed through the app, the body stream has been read (usually by `ring.middleware.params/assoc-form-params`, which calls `slurp` on the request body) and is now empty.

In other words, if you're testing a ring app with ring-mock, you should never reuse a request with a body. It's probably best to always create a new request.